# EDIT Return the correct date value when the character amount changes

Tags: excel, date, substitution

I need this data to be formatted as a date and the only issue with my current formulae, is that some of the data shows only one digit as the day when the rest show two digits. Below shows the current formulas, the data always appears as this, in between two parenthesises, the data below is the extent of the variation.

[image: Image of data]

[image: Data with formulas]

- [EDIT] After applying this formula
  (=DATEVALUE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2)+1,LEN(A2)- FIND("-",A2)-1)) )          to the source data i realised that the variation in the data was more complex than my example (apologies), the formula fails when applied to this data. below shows what i mean the source data had alot of variation.

[image: with the data (lots of variation)]

[image: with formulae]

Comment: Instead of screenshots, which we can't copy/paste from, could you post your data in a table instead? Also the formulas you are using.  Also, does this work `=LEFT(MID(A1,SEARCH("- ",A1)+2,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("- ",A1)+1),LEN(A1)-SEARCH("- ",A1)-2)`, assuming `(name - Aug 17, 2015)` is in `A1`?

Comment: Thank yours also worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one formula should do what you want:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)- FIND("-",A1)-1))
```

You will need to format the output cell as a date.

[image]

Comment: @G198 glad to help, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: just made and edit, if you can see the data variation, i tried to apply your formula to my source data but it failed to pick up the correct text.

Comment: @G198 changing the question after getting an answer is considered inappropriate in this forum.  Try modifying for the exception.  If you are unable to pose a new question with what you tried and link back to this question for reference.  Also it is always better to post your data as text and not a picture.  Pictures should be back up to show setup not data.